# mtr output: last entry is repeated on all hops

Tags: networking, ping, traceroute

Whenever I run `mtr`, it briefly shows a single hop per line, then upon reaching the last hop it shows up as a duplicate entry on all other hops:

```
                         My traceroute  [v0.92]
[local hostname] ([local ip])                    2019-10-17T12:40:35-0300
Keys:  Help   Display mode   Restart statistics   Order of fields   quit
                                Packets               Pings
 Host                Loss%   Snt   Last   Avg  Best  Wrst StDev
 1. [ip1]             0.0%     4   19.7   5.6   0.8  19.7   9.4
    [ip]
 2. [ip2]             0.0%     4    0.9   0.8   0.7   0.9   0.1
    [ip]
 3. [ip3]             0.0%     3    7.4   3.7   1.2   7.4   3.3
    [ip]
 4. [ip]              0.0%     3    0.6   0.7   0.6   0.8   0.1
```

This doesn't happen on `traceroute`:

```
$ traceroute [domain] 
traceroute to [domain] ([ip]), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  [ip1] ([ip1])  1.369 ms  1.322 ms  1.309 ms
 2  [ip2] ([ip2])  1.248 ms  1.218 ms  1.196 ms
 3  [ip3] ([ip3])  38.997 ms  38.988 ms  39.416 ms
 4  [ip] ([ip])  1.034 ms  1.005 ms  0.973 ms
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Isn't it just saying it is searching for that IP?

Comment: Can you compare `traceroute` with `sudo traceroute --icmp`, and likewise `mtr` with `mtr --udp`?